# How to handle Adf bootstrap metadata adfc-mobile-config.xml is null exception

Tags: java, oracle-adf, adfc-config

I get an **exception** as "*bootstrap metadata adfc-mobile-config.xml is null*" everytime i try to run a **feature** of my **ADF Mobile Application**.

Here is what i did to solve the issue:

1. Copied all the **beans** that i use in task flow to **adfc-mobile-config.xml**.
2. Changed the **feature**'s name.

Problem persists.

Has anybody any clue about the causes of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/11gr2update3-1851251.html

"bootstrap.html bootstrap metadata document adfc-mobile-config.xml is null" (14233159)
Applies to: iOS and Android

Using feature name with multi-byte chars sometimes causes the following error: 
"bootstrap.html bootstrap metadata document adfc-mobile-config.xml is null" .

Also check if your ResourceBundle file has any special characters or something like ????

Comment: Thanks but i've unfortunately already seen that and it didn't work.